# Finding the maximum integer of three integers in C

Tags: c

I just started learning how to code in C.
I tried creating a program that finds the maximum of three integers using arrays, but I don't really understand why does it work.

Can anybody more experienced help explain to me; why do I need to let max = 0 in order for the program to function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int size, max;
  int arr[3];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("Please enter your integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
  } 

  max = 0;

  for (int i = 0; arr[i] >= max; i++) {
    max = arr[i];
  }

  printf("This is the max number: %d", max);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Well simply because you're testing against it, it needs an initial value. However, it should not be zero, it should be `INT_MIN` instead. Also, your program will produce an incorrect result with an input sequence such as, 3, 1, 7. Figuring out why, is left for the reader as homework. :)

Comment: Think about your algorithm. What will the result be if all the input values are negative numbers? Hint: if you initialize Max to 0 then all the entered numbers will be less than Max.

Answer (score 2):

The proper loop would be:

```
int max= INT_MIN;
for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
   if (arr[i]> max) max= arr[i];
```

Comment: zero as an initial value will produce incorrect results with negative inputs.

Comment: It might be worth adding a note to include limits.h for the definition of `INT_MIN`.

Comment: Would it be correct if I initialize ?
           int max = arr [0];

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. You can start he loop then at `i=1`.

Comment: @vmt, because if it is not the max, then another will be found that is the max.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, took a second too long for me to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

A variable must be initialized before it can be used. The first use of `max` is:

```c
for (int i = 0; arr[i] >= max; i++) {
    ...         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

The boundary condition in a `for` loop (i.e. `arr[i] >= max`) is evaluated *before* every iteration of the loop. A value for `max` is therefore required before the body of the loop is ever executed.

Thus, you must assign some value to `max` outside the loop, and, as you discovered, `max = 0` is a suitable initial value *for some inputs*.

However as mentioned by Paul in the comments, this is not a suitable boundary condition for the result you’re trying to achieve. You should instead iterate over the entire array, setting the `max` value only if each array element is greater than the existing `max` value:

```c
max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > max) {
        max = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: But this loop terminates when not `arr[i] >= max` and when i==1 then values of i==2 is not evaluated: wrong loop condition!

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You’re right; I was focussed on the main question and completely missed that!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code won't find the right answer in all test cases, and that's because of how you wrote your second `for` loop. For example if you have an input like `3, 2, 4`, after the first for iteration you'll have `max = 3` and the for loop will stop because the next element (2) is less than the current max (3). But the max value of this array is 4, not 3. You should change the second for loop like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
     (if array[i]>max) max = array[i]; 
}
```

Also, take note that you can initialize `max` to 0 only if you don't have negative numbers in the array, otherwise you might have incorrect results. So, if you can't make assumptions about your input values I would suggest you to simply initialize `max` with the first element of the array and do a loop starting from the second one to the end `(for(i=1;i<3;i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for three:

```
#define MAX_SIMPLE(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ?(a) :(b))

int a[3] = {3, 2, 1};

printf("max is: %d\n", MAX_SIMPLE(a[0], MAX_SIMPLE(a[1], a[2])));
```

Comment: Can you help explain what does this code do?

                                                               
  `#define MAX_SIMPLE(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ?(a) :(b))`